# Cut the String in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a string in excel such as "Ariel Block SC-01-06" but I want only "SC-01-06". Which formula should I use?

For example, the name is like 'FSC Block SC-02-07', I want only the last part which is right after the last space in the name.

The only formula i came up with is this,

```
=RIGHT(A1,FIND(" ",A1))
```

... but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You'll have to mention a little more about the data you have. Is it always Ariel Block you want to remove? Can it be `JohnSmith SC-01-06`? Can it be `Ariel Block Matthews AB-11-22`? Can it be `John Smith Really ABCDE-12345-54321`? Can it be `Aerial A-1-2-3-4-5-6`?

Comment: @zedfoxus Thanks, I already updated my question. In the name, I only want the part of the name which is right after the last space of the string

Answer (score 6):

Expand the last space (actually all spaces) to the width of the original whole string then crop off the right end and trim it to receive the last space delimited 'element'.

```
=trim(right(substitute(a1, " ", rept(" ", len(a1))), len(a1)))
```

The native worksheet [REPT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/REPT-function-04C4D778-E712-43B4-9C15-D656582BB061) is the equvilent of VBA's [Space](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278869.aspx) function.

Comment: That's a great solution!

Comment: @Jeeped, I have used the Rept solution a bajillion times but always hard coded 255, using the Len of the original never occurred to me, what an elegant solution.

Comment: @DanDonoghue - yes I used to habitually use 99 or 999 but using the width of the actual string provides more of a one-size-fits-all universality.

Comment: @chrisneilsen - It's not really necessary for this formula; I included it out of habit (avoiding errors with Find) but I should remove it from this. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want to use as your delimiter or pattern for deciding which part of the string to discard, but for now I will assume that the **last** space in your string marks the **start** of the string that you want to keep. If that's the case, then you can use a reverse string search (see: http://www.exceltactics.com/reverse-string-search-excel-using-find/4/). For example:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ",A1)),A1,RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","~",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))))))
```

For more of an explanation about how this works, see the start of the original article: http://www.exceltactics.com/reverse-string-search-excel-using-find/

If you had some other method of detecting where your desired string starts, and you could determine that as a number (e.g. character index number 13 onwards), you could just use `=MID(A1, (your_function_here), LEN(A1))`